# Unexpected behavior trying to add a custom representer to Python yaml module?

Tags: python, serialization, yaml, pyyaml

I want to dump a dictionary containing ip addresses (as `ipaddress.IPv4Network` objects) as YAML. Following [the docs](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), I tried the following:

```py
import ipaddress
import yaml


def address_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', str(data))


yaml.add_representer(ipaddress.IPv4Network, address_representer)
print(yaml.safe_dump({'network': ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24')}))
```

But this fails with:

```
  [...]
  File "/home/lars/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 231, in represent_undefined
    raise RepresenterError("cannot represent an object", data)
yaml.representer.RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the docs use ``add_representer`` only together with ``safe``, and further say "``safe_dump`` produces only standard YAML tags and cannot represent an arbitrary Python object."

Comment: I'm not sure what do with that comment: the goal here is to transform a Python object into a simple string, so that it is compatible with `safe_dump`.

Comment: I had a typo – ``safe`` should have been ``dump``. To put it another way: ``print(yaml.dump({'network': ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24')}))`` works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do yaml.safe_dump() and .safe_load() of Python object without yaml.YAMLObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906676/how-to-do-yaml-safe-dump-and-safe-load-of-python-object-without-yaml-yamlob)

Comment: Calling `yaml.SafeDumper.add_representer` was the solution. Thanks!